# Code works on codeacademy's site, but won't work on coderbyte

Tags: javascript, arrays, compiler-errors

I'm having problems with the code below, and it's really frustrating. The problem isn't seemingly the code itself: the program works just fine to find the second greatest and lowest numbers in an array, but only does so on the labs.codeacademy.com JavaScript environment thus far.

I went to Coderbyte.org to enter the correct code to pass the challenge. First, whenever I type, "input.sort(function(a,b){return (a-b);});" into coderbyte.org's site, it indents the remainder of the block from the middle of the page for some reason. This makes me think it could be the source of my problem.

When I cut and paste my code from codeacademy to coderbyte.org's website, it pastes with fine indentation, however it only returns a blank box instead of the second highest and lowest values still. My question: why does it work on one site, but not the other? I've been going nuts on this for two days: someone please help me?

```
function SecondGreatestLow(arr) {  
    input.sort(function(a,b){return (a-b);});  
    var input = arr;  
    var hashObject = {}  

    for (var i = input.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var currentItem = input[i]; //WE LOOP THROUGH OUR NUMBER LIST

        if (hashObject[currentItem] === true) {
            input.splice(i, 1); //IF CURRENTITEM IS ALREADY IN HASHOBJECT, THEN DELETE THE COPY FOUND IN ARRAY AND MOVE ON TO NEXT NUMBER
        }

        hashObject[currentItem] = true; //IF CURRENTITEM IS NOT IN HASHOBJECT, ADD IT! THEN MOVE ON TO NEXT NUMBER.
    }
    //THE ARRAY HAS NOW BEEN "DE-DUPED":
    //NEXT WE OUTPUT THE MAX AND MIN VALUES ACCORDING TO ARRAY SIZE
    if (input.length >= 4) { //If 4+ chars, then remove the first two values to access the second by default
        input.pop(); 
        input.shift();
        var min = Math.min.apply(null,input),
        max = Math.max.apply(null,input);
        return (max + " " + min);
    } else {
        var min2 = Math.min.apply(null,input), 
        max2 = Math.max.apply(null,input);
        return max2 + " " + min2;
    }
}

//example:   
console.log(SecondGreatestLow(arr));  
// THE OUTPUT ON CODEACADEMY IS AS FOLLOWS:  
// arr = [ 1, 5, 10, 1, 25, 1, 5, 5, 5, 40, 5, 1, 100 ]; -> 40 5  
// arr = [ 4, 90 ]; -> 90 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

- You define `input` after you try to sort it
- You have to actually call your function on an array if you want it to output something (I assume you did this, but it would surprise you how many people forget; also, some editors will show you what's returned and others will require you to output it somewhere since, essentially, you're calling a function without doing anything with it; CCLabs is nice about this in that it shows the return values for every function call)

[image]

Comment: I see the error with input: thanks. I also realized that my array size at the end of the function is "if (input >= 4) {...", which works in CC. But in Coderbyte, I had to switch it to "if (input > 2) {..." in order to make it work for some reason. Plus, yes, I did accidentally delete the function call on Coderbyte too, incidentally. THANK YOU FOR THE FAST RESPONSE!